# Obtaining road information from route

Tags: openstreetmap, gps, road, route

I need to obtain information (road surface typology, max speed limit etc.) on all the roads that make my route, from A to B.
The inputs of my problem will be waypoints, obtained by GPS coordinates.

I need to extract road information based on these spatial way points.
I know it's possible to find these types of information from overpass turbo, but it has not helped me, since I don't know how to extract the route path given by the points.

Comment: Check out https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#module-osmnx.geometries. You can extract OSM data based on points or polygons, an address or by defining a bounding box.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've seen it, but my idea is to make a route (route made by the union of ways) and then having all the information about the ways.